# Yeoman Generator for Dynamically adding Code

Tags: android, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to build a Yeoman project generator for android that can take parameters from users and update the already present file accordingly. Like it can put some boiler plate code into the file or add dependency in build.gradle etc at runtime.

For example 
I prompt user if he want to add library dependency for Fabric, if he press yes then the dependency for that library

`compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }`

should be added in build.gradle and should add the code require to setup this library in necessary files like Application class onCreate method should contain

`Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`

and Android.Manifest should contain

`<meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="your key">`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd want to parse and modify the AST from your source file. But I don't know if you'll find AST parsers for java code (for XML code, it should be easy).

```
const source = this.fs.read(this.destinationPath('file-to-modify.xml'));
const manifest = parseXML(source); // any XML parser will work here

// Here you write the code to modify the XML source

this.fs.write(
  this.destinationPath('file-to-modify.xml'),
  serializeXML(manifest) // with whichever XML serializer you want to use
);
```

For the Java code, if there's no proper AST parser, you can always rely on regex to inject the new lines in the code string in a similar fashion to the xml example.